# Multiple DataReader Error despite separate Connection

Tags: .net, sql-server

I've been receiving the error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first" when trying to connect to a SQL Server Express database.

It seems that a blunt solution to this is to turn on MARS, but I'm not convinced that my situation is appropriate - especially since (I thought) I was using two separate connections.

The minimum code that I'm using to replicate the issue is below.  I thought that because I have two separate connections (conn1 and conn2) that any open reader on conn1 would not affect conn2, yet when I try to call conn2.Open() I get the error.

```
    Dim constr As String = "Initial Catalog=myDB;Data Source=(local);User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXX"

    Using conn1 = New SqlConnection(constr)
        Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("GetApprovals", conn1)
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("jobID", jobID)
        conn1.Open()
        Using reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
            Do While reader1.Read()
                Using conn2 = New SqlConnection(constr)
                    conn2.Open()
                End Using
            Loop
        End Using

    End Using
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was to do with Transactions.  An important point that I didn't note (didn't think it was relevant) was that the code in question was being run from inside an MBUnit Unit Test.

The test had the Rollback() decorator set, thus running everything inside a Transaction.  It seems that in this scenario, even though I was explicitly creating a new SQLConnection, because it was within the Transaction it would re-use the connection, leading to the error.

The fix was to instruct the secondary/inner connection not to enlist in transactions by appending "`;enlist=false;`" to the end of the connection string used to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

By default the SqlConnection object will attempt to pool your connection for identical connection strings

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx:

> When a connection is first opened, a connection pool is created based on an exact matching algorithm that associates the pool with the connection string in the connection. Each connection pool is associated with a distinct connection string. When a new connection is opened, if the connection string is not an exact match to an existing pool, a new pool is created.

You can try adding the ["Max Pool Size=1"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) setting to your connection string to force a new connection to be opened for your second statement.

Comment: Setting a `Max Pool Size=1` seems to just cause a timeout waiting for an available connection.  In testing this out, however, it set me off on a path to discover the actual problem.  Thanks.